# Plotting multiple lines on a graph

Tags: vba, excel, plot, graph

I am attempting to plot a graph which has a number of Series plotted on the same axis. So we have:

```
    Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    Set ChartRange1 = Sheets("Series_2").Range("$E$8:$E20$") 
    ChartRangeAddr1 = ChartRange1.Address(External:=True)
    Set ChartRange2 = Sheets("Series_3").Range("$E$8:$E$20")
    ChartRangeAddr2 = ChartRange2.Address(External:=True)
    (we could have many more here)
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(ChartRangeAddr1, ChartRangeAddr2)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Series_1!$D$8:$D20"
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Dates"
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "USD"
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
```

Note: Series_1 and Series_2 are data taken from different sheets. For some reason this code is only producing series one on the graph. Please, can anyone correct a mistake I am not seeing or point my compass to a solution to the general problem of plotting more than one line onto a graph in VBA. thanks

Answer (score 0):

see if you can add a line like:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).YValues = "=Series_2!$E$8:$E20$"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).YValues = "=Series_3!$E$8:$E20$"
```

I find that when you record a macro it sometimes skips important steps.

Answer (score 0):

SetSourceData only works with data on one sheet. You could do this (skip ChartRange1Address etc.):

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ChartRange1
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Series_1!$D$8:$D20"
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = ChartRange2
End With
```